# Connect to local sql server from docker container

Tags: docker, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pyodbc

I try the following to accomplish:
Connect to a loacl sql server on a windows machine using a docker image.
The problem I am facing is that there is no successful connection, the main error I get with different configurations is:

```html
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I tried:

- different drivers
- checked tcp protocol enabled on port 1433 (sql server configuration manager) + allow remote connections
- different docker images
- different connection strings

Setup:

- pyodbc + sqlalchemy with engine notation
- fastAPI backend with uvicorn

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = (
    "mssql+pyodbc://user_name:user_password@127.0.0.1:1433/db_name"
    "?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
)

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL,
    echo=True,

)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

Dockerfile:
Odbc Installation driver from:
[Microsoft Driver Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=alpine18-install%2Cdebian17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Cubuntu16-13-install%2Crhel7-offline#13)

```
# 
FROM python:3.11.1

# 
WORKDIR /code

# 
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc

#Download appropriate package for the OS version
#Choose only ONE of the following, corresponding to your OS version


#Debian 11
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list


RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
#RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
#RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
#RUN source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
# optional: kerberos library for debian-slim distributions
RUN apt-get install -y libgssapi-krb5-2


# 
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt



# 
COPY ./app /code/app

# 
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5001"]
```

The docker build is successful and I run it wirh:

```
docker run -d --name container_name -p 1433:1433 dockerhub_name/image_name:latest
```

The container runs fro a few seconds and then says:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I think it is a network issue, but cant get my head arround :S
The main hint i tried to follow also was:
[question from July](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63012538/configuring-sqlalchemy-with-pyodbc-on-docker-getting-interface-error)

With the answer from @J.C. Gras

Answer (score 1):

using "host.docker.internal" instead of localhost fixed my issue